# Removing the group summary field from AdvancedDatagridColumn

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I have a AdvancedDataGridColumn with custom itemrenderer which displays undefined in the group summary field. How do I get rid of it? I have included the code and a screenshot

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="import_type" headerText="Workflow">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
                <s:Label left="5" right="5" verticalCenter="0"
                         text="{data.import_type} , {data.export_type}"/>
            </s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="import_type" headerText="Workflow">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
                <s:Label left="5" right="5" verticalCenter="0"
                         text="{(data.import_type == undefined)?'':data.import_type} {(data.import_type!=undefined &amp;&amp; data.export_type!=undefined)?',':''} {(data.export_type==undefined)?'':data.export_type}"/>
            </s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Why do we need to use "&amp;&amp;" instead of "&&"?

Comment: Since it's in MXML and it expects good XML it complains about the & by itself but &amp; gets replaced I think during the conversion from MXML to AS and it works.  At least that's the best I understand it just something I learned from trying and failing though. "Experience is a dear teacher, and only fools will learn from no other." Ben Franklin